# VBA InStr with multiple Strings

Tags: string, vba, if-statement

I want to check multiple strings with   `InStr` and replace them if necessary.

Something like:

```
s1 = "ABC"  s2 = "ABCD" s3 = "ABCDE"

If InStr(s1,"D") <> 0 Then
   s1 = ""
End If
If InStr(s2,"D") <> 0 Then
   s2 = ""
End If
If InStr(s3,"D") <> 0 Then
   s3 = ""
End If
```

I'm sure there is a easier and more intuitive way to do this but i just dont know how.
Maybe with `Loop` or `Case` ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Case select would be best for this.

Comment: since you are repeating the same code multiple times consider writing a function and calling that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Case` is a solution.

`Array` is another solution. You can populate your values to an array and do a `For Loop` for each value in the array.

Answer to similar question:

> [InStr array is in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16213498/instr-array-is-in-string)

Comment: Your similar question is foo bar. This is a VBA question, not a VB.NET question.